# Javascript nested collapsible divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a collapsible div, which has another collapsible div nested inside:

```
<button class="collapsible">Expand First Panel</button>

<div class="firstPanel">
    <div class="fistPanelContent"> ••• </div>
        
    <button>Expand Second Panel</button>

    <div class="secondPanel">
        Content of the second panel
    </div>
</div>
```

On click of the first button, the `firstPanel` div should expand, and upon clicking the nested second button, the `secondPanel` div should expand.

I've managed to achieve a single expanding div by using `overflow: hidden;` and a script to change the div's max height:

```
<script>
var allCollapsibles = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");

// Iterate through the collapsibles
var index;
for (index = 0; index < allCollapsibles.length; index++) {

    // Add expansion toggle
    allCollapsibles[index].addEventListener("click", function() {
        // Set max height for collapsible element
        var expandableContent = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (expandableContent.style.maxHeight) {
            expandableContent.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            expandableContent.style.maxHeight = expandableContent.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

... but this won't work for the second expanding div, because I've set the first div's max height

How could I get the second div to expand, whilst it's inside the first div?

Comment: Is this question about re-implementing the behaviour of `<summary>`/`<details>`, or is it because of not knowing about them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution for your markup. It is much simpler to just add and remove a class like `show` instead of going down the road and doing height calculations. You can then add or remove the class `show` depending if the item already has the class or not. With css you can hide or show the item.

```js
var allCollapsibles = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
allCollapsibles.forEach( item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", function() {
     if(this.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('show')) {
       this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('show')
     } else {
       this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('show')
     }
  });
});
```

```css
.firstPanel,
.secondPanel {
  display: none;
}

.firstPanel.show,
.secondPanel.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible">Expand First Panel</button>
<div class="firstPanel">
    <div class="fistPanelContent"> ••• </div>
        
    <button class="collapsible">Expand Second Panel</button>

    <div class="secondPanel">
        Content of the second panel
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest "enabling CSS", instead of your disabling one. Dfiference: The former only applies under certain conditions, the latter applies changes and undoes the changes under certain conditions. In this case, it could look like this: `.firstPanel:not(.show) {display: none}`

Comment: @OskarGrosser yes I agree. Also it would be even simpler to only have a class `hide` which is already present at the beginning. But then the answer was there and like so it shows kinda all possible ways. Now everyone can be creative.